# Deserialise a JSON string to nested objects using jsons

Tags: json, python-3.x, object, python-dataclasses

I am trying to deserialise a json string to an object using [jsons](https://jsons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but having problems with nested objects, but can't work out the syntax.

As an example the following code attempts to define the data structure as a series of dataclasses but fails to deserialise the nested objects C and D ? The syntax is clearly wrong, but its not clear to me how it should structured

```
import jsons
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class D:
    E: str
class C:
    id: int
    name:str
@dataclass
class test:
    A: str
    B: int
    C: C()
    D: D()

jsonString = {"A":"a","B":1,"C":[{"id":1,"name":"one"},{"id":2,"name":"two"}],"D":[{"E":"e"}]}
instance = jsons.load(jsonString, test)
```

Can anyone indicate the correct way to deserialise the objects from json ?

Comment: Does it need to be a `dataclass` or can you just use `namedtuples`.

Comment: I am not wedded to a `dataClass` (this is what `jsons` uses and is clean, but class C and D also have associated methods (which I haven't detailed in this example). I could extend a `namedtuples` but this then gets messy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two relatively simple problems with your attempt:

1. You forgot to decorate `C` with `@dataclass`.
2. `Test.C` and `Test.D` aren't defined with types, but with *instances* of the types. (Further, you want both fields to be *lists* of the given type, not single instances of each.)

Given the code

```
import jsons
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class D:
    E: str


@dataclass  # Problem 1 fixed
class C:
    id: int
    name: str


@dataclass
class Test:
    A: str
    B: int
    C: List[C]  # Problem 2 fixed; List[C] not C() or even C
    D: List[D]  # Problem 2 fixed; List[D], not D() or even D
```

Then

```
>>> obj = {"A":"a", "B":1, "C": [{"id": 1,"name": "one"}, {"id": 2, "name": "two"}], "D":[{"E": "e"}]}
>>> jsons.load(obj, Test)
test(A='a', B=1, C=[C(id=1, name='one'), C(id=2, name='two')], D=[D(E='e')])
```

Comment: Thanks, #1 was a typo, but  #2 was exactly what I was missing

Comment: Whilst I can understand why `test.C` needs to be added as a list as there are multiple instances, this is not the case for `test.D` as there is only one instance. For example, if I initialise `test` directly as follows `instance = test(D=D(E="e"))`, `test.D` is defined as an object `D` not a `List`. Similarly, is there a type definition for `test.D` to avoid defining as a `List` ?

Comment: There's only one, but it's still a *list* of one item. If your Python `dict` could be `{..., "D": {"E": "e"}}` as well, you'll need to define `D` with a *union* type `Union[D,List[D]]`.

Comment: Thanks, but `Union[D,List[D]]` still defines `D` as a `List` of one item not as a single object `D` of `test`

Comment: More precisely, the type hint provided to the dataclass doesn't affect what values you can assign to the field directly, but `jsons` does appear to take the type hints into account.

Comment: @Marky0 It shouldn't; with `obj='{..., "D": {"E": "e"}}"`, `jsons.dump` produces `Test(..., D=D(E='e'))`, not `Test(..., D=[D(E='e')])`.

Comment: My error. I have just spotted that `D` is defined as a `List` in the json string, and therefore your suggestion of `Union[D,List[D]` works perfectly. Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class D(ValidatedDC):
    E: str


@dataclass
class C(ValidatedDC):
    id: int
    name: str


@dataclass
class Test(ValidatedDC):
    A: str
    B: int
    C: List[C]
    D: List[D]


jsonString = {
    "A": "a",
    "B": 1,
    "C": [{"id": 1, "name": "one"}, {"id": 2, "name": "two"}],
    "D": [{"E": "e"}]
}

instance = Test(**jsonString)

assert instance.C == [C(id=1, name='one'), C(id=2, name='two')]
assert instance.C[0].id == 1
assert instance.C[1].name == 'two'

assert instance.D == [D(E='e')]
assert instance.D[0].E == 'e'
```

ValidatedDC: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
# First parameter is the class/tuple name, second parameter
# is a space delimited string of varaibles.
# Note that the variable names should match the keys from 
# your dictionary of arguments unless only one argument is given.
A = namedtuple("A", "a_val") # Here the argument `a_val` can be called something else
B = namedtuple("B", "num")
C = namedtuple("C", "id name")
D = namedtuple("D", "E") # This must be `E` since E is the key in the dictionary.
# If you dont want immutable objects to can use full classes
# instead of namedtuples

# A dictionary which matches the name of an object seen in a payload
# to the object we want to create for that name.
object_options = {
  "A": A,
  "B": B,
  "C": C,
  "D": D
}
my_objects = [] # This is the list of object we get from the payload

jsonString = {"A":"a","B":1,"C":[{"id":1,"name":"one"},{"id":2,"name":"two"}],"D":[{"E":"e"}]}

for key, val in jsonString.items():
    if key in object_options: # If this is a valid object
        if isinstance(val, list): # If it is a list of this object
            for v in val: # Then we need to add each object in the list
                my_objects.append(object_options[key](**v))
        elif isinstance(val, dict): # If the object requires a dict then pass the whole dict as arugments
            my_objects.append(object_options[key](**val))
        else: # Else just add this object with a singular argument.
            my_objects.append(object_options[key](val))
print(my_objects)
```

**Output:**

```
[A(a_val='a'), B(num=1), C(id=1, name='one'), C(id=2, name='two'), D(E='e')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to get this to work by removing the `dataClass` definition and expanding the class definitions old school.... code as follows...

```
import jsons

class D:
     def __init__(self, E = ""):
         self.E = E
class C:
    def __init__(self, id = 0, name=""):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
class test:
    def __init__(self, A = "", B = 0, C = C(), D = D()):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.D = D

jsonString = {"A":"a","B":1,"C":[{"id":1,"name":"one"},{"id":2,"name":"two"}],"D":[{"E":"e"}]}
instance = jsons.load(jsonString, test)
```

It now works but is not as clean as with a `dataClass`. Grateful if anyone can indicate how the original post can be constructed with the `dataClass` definition.